# Is it possible to stop Terminal from running a specific command on MacOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app

I'm looking for a way to stop a specific command from being ran on MacOS's terminal, or if that's not possible lock it (either with a different password than the user password, or time lock it) before running - is that possible?

Comment: Build a batch like process to run the command and make the batch command to require Admin Credentials.

Comment: Would it work for you to just define an alias that overrides it to do nothing? `alias <command>=""`?

Comment: (The alias could be undone though with `unalias`)

Comment: @user: or suppressed by quoting any character(s) of it like `\grep` or `'grep'` .

Comment: I tried using ```alias <command>=""```, replacing the "command" with my specific command, but it didn't work - did I do the right step?

Comment: alias only works if the command is at the beginning of the commandline IIRC (not sure if that's what you're running into). You could also try redefining the command as a bash function that does nothing.